# Insert a SpannableStringBuilder into another SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spanned

I have a `SpannableStringBuilder` object that applies some formatting to its text. Now I'd like to insert another formatted string into this object. I can see that `SpannableStringBuilder` has an `insert()` method, but it only accepts a `CharSequence` which doesn't allow me to apply any text formatting.

So I am wondering if it is possible to insert a `SpannableStringBuilder` object into another `SpannableStringBuilder` object in any way or do I have to rebuild the complete `SpannableStringBuilder` object if I need to insert formatted text into it?

Answer (score 0):

You mean that both the destination and source SpannableStringBuilders have spans attached, right?

[SpannableStringBuilder.replace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int)) - which insert() uses internally - says

> If source is Spanned, the spans from it are preserved into the
>   Editable

so it should work.

However, it only seems to work if dest does not already contain the span that source is trying to insert. See this comment:

// Add span only if this object is not yet used as a span in this string

in SpannableStringBuilder.java

I'm not sure why its been implemented with this constraint.